# Нет доступа к корню локальной копии сайта на WordPress в MAMP

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

Распаковал бэкап сайта в нужную папку. PhpMyAdmin видит все базы данных используемые. Но при попытке перехода по адресу запущенного локального сервера (где и находится локальная копия сайта) вижу ошибку:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Может быть надо переходить не по адресу localhost, а по адресу localhost/<имя директории проекта>  ?

Comment: @MiMEKiZ в папке htdocs у меня находится папка с бэкапом сайта. Я сразу ее в MAMP поставил в качестве корня. [https://i.imgur.com/jn4Znrv.jpg]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress